# What bike crank do I have and how can I re-attach?

Tags: crankset, mechanical

So during quarantine i've picked up a hobby of bike riding. Recently while going for an afternoon bike ride I noticed one my pedals were shaking but I just ignored it. When I was finished riding I parked up my bike in the garage and I checked to see what the problem was. While inspecting/testing both my pedals one of the cranks just fell off. It turned out being only the crank was the problem. I was trying to figure out how to re-attach it looking at numerous threads and videos on the internet with no luck. I noticed my crank was different from a lot of the others I seen on the internet (mine having no bolt at all). This bike has been chilling in my garage for years unused (nor do i remember how it ended up there lol) so I couldn't tell you what type of bike it is or the model. Here are some photos

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Need a better picture of the end of the crank axle.  And pry out the cap covering the hole in the crank.

Comment: It looks like the head of the crank bolt sheared off, and the crank worked its way off the bottom-bracket spindle. I'd take it to a shop and let them fix it.

Comment: I am suspicious about the marks around the end of the crank. Its not a normal place to see that kind of damage.  I wonder if someone has done some 'percussion' maintenance on it in the past.  It looks like square taper in which case the crank probably needs replacing.

Comment: @DanielRHicks thanks, i could try

Comment: @AdamRice yeahh i figured that would be the case, thank you

Comment: @mattnz thanks, i might just take it to a shop and see

Comment: @Criggie when i look inside the crank all i see is the bottom of the silver cap on top but i will still try this tomorrow, if anything i will just have to take it to a shop. thanks

Comment: The hole of the crank-arm is no longer square. That crank-arm is dead and it's risky to put it back on. It can never be tightened properly again, will always be wobbly and could cause the axle to break. You may be able to find a fitting second-hand left crank at a bike-shop.

Comment: It vaguely looks like there's a nut in the crank arm.  You need to pull the cap off to see.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the new photos, there's a nut missing.  Its been loose for a while, because the square taper hole is a bit wallowed-out.  That may have killed the crank arm, have to try refitting it to be sure.

You need a suitable nut that fits the threads on your bike's bottom bracket axle, if the old one is not trapped in the head of the crank.

I'd pop off the silver cap in the middle, lightly grease the taper, then refit the crank arm.  Then fit the nut and do it up tight with a socket - you can't use a spanner on this because its recessed.

---

I suspect this crank has been loose for a while.  You probably didn't cause this oritginally, but have exacerbated it by continuing to ride with the loose crank.

Tomorrow, retighten the nut again.  The crank will slide harder onto the taper over time.  Since its already damaged, you may as well try to save it.

If it breaks then you needed a new one anyway!

Check locally for a Bike Cooperative or similar - a left-hand crank arm, square taper shouldn't be uncommon.  It may be that you need a new bottom bracket axle too, depending if there's damage to the taper.

---

The reason yours has a (missing) nut and not a bolt is that its an older design, functionally the same.  A more recent cartridge BB would have tapped holes in the ends for bolts, the effective differences are a tiny bit of weight saved,  requires less space under the cap allowing for thinner cranks, and a smaller box volume.